# selenium python clicking and looping on elements inside elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a group of elements on the page that looks like:

```
<div class="course-lesson__course-wrapper" data-qa-level="z1">
   <div class="course-lesson__course-title">
   <section class="course-lesson__wrap" data-qa-lesson="trial">
   <section class="course-lesson__wrap" data-qa-lesson="trial">
```

There are several pages with this layout. I want to get a list of all the elements in z1 and then click on them if it is a `data-qa-lesson="trial"`

I have this code

```
#finds all the elements for z1 - ...etc
listofA1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.course-lesson__course-wrapper:nth-child(1)")
for elemen in listofA1:
    #checks for the attribute i need to see if it's clickable
    elementcheck = elemen.getAttribute("data-qa-lesson")
    if elementcheck == "objective":
        elemen.click()

        #do some stuff then go back to main and begin again on the next element
        driver.get(home_link)
```

But it does not seem to work

Comment: _But it does not seem to work_: What actually happens?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium It only gets the top element and doesn't loop because there is one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `StaleElementException` you can try this approach:

```
count = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-qa-level="z1"]//div[@data-qa-level="trial"]'))  # Get count of elements

for i in range(count):
    driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-qa-level="z1"]//div[@data-qa-level="trial"]')[i].click() # click current element
    # Do what you need
    driver.get(home_link)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. But it lead me to the answer. For some reason that xpath didn't work. But I got it to work with css selectors. Using the latest selenium